# How to test an iPhone application update before sending to review app

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

When i update my app from old to new version from App Store, all data i lost

I m not able to test what happens when an app updated, if there is any method to test it before review then its better to resolve issue.

Also not able to test where the data is deleted or is there but not displaying.

Please help me regarding this.

thank u

Comment: You can use TestFlight for testing the app before review. whenever you upload the app to App Store, that app will be available in the TestFlight.

Comment: i want to test it before sending to App Store, is this possible

Comment: Not sure, if it's in my case i will do like this. Please download the old app from Appstore and then connect iPhone and run code, so you can easily debug too

Comment: thank u, but i did that not able to reproduce that error